# Checking that a string of the date and time is for the most recent hour

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

In my script I have a string containing the date and the time in the following format:

```
>>>mystring.text
'05/08/201714:00:00'
```

What is the best way to compare the string with the output from the datetime.now() method to check if the string contains the most recent hour?  Basically, what is the 'operation' I need to do in order to make the following conditional statement:

```
time = operation(mystring.text)

if time  ==  datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0,second=0,minute=0):
    pass
```

Comment: Checkout `datetime.datetime.strptime()` .

Comment: Your use of parentheses makes no sense.

Comment: sorry, I copy and pasted it and forgot to take out closing parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

It would be probably make sense to do the comparison in `datetime` format as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

mystring = "05/08/201714:00:00"
dt_mystring = datetime.strptime(mystring, "%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S")

print dt_mystring.replace(microsecond=0,second=0,minute=0) == datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0,second=0,minute=0)eplace(microsecond=0,second=0,minute=0)
```

[`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime) is used to convert your string into a `datetime` object.
The formatting characters are: [`strptime() Behavior`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)